# Google Tag Manager vs. Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm attempting to learn how to incorporate Google Analytics and custom event tracking on a new website. After researching into it, I can't seem to understand the difference and relationship between Google Tag Manager and just writing custom event tracking code.

Is Google Tag Manager just an easier way to track information without having to write JS?

Comment: **Duplicate Question** 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640645/what-is-the-difference-between-google-tag-manager-and-google-analytics

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes - Google Tag Manager is a "Tag Management System" wherein you can implement a lot of tags external of a typical development release cycle.

> Adding tags without efficient management prompts big problems. All that code bogs down your site. Redundant or incorrectly applied tags can distort your measurement and result in duplicate costs or missing data. And it can be time-consuming for the IT department or webmaster team to add new tags, which means important marketing and measurement programs can be delayed. With Google Tag Manager, you eliminate these problems—and run your campaigns when you need them. -- [source](https://www.google.com/tagmanager/faq.html)

> Marketing and tracking services provide “tags” — snippets of code you’re often asked to embed right before the end of your tag — and they’re relatively easy to use, but when more than a few tags are involved, managing them can be a tedious task. This is where Google’s new Tag Manager comes in, which consolidates all of your site’s tags into a single admin panel. Now, you only have to include one automatically-updated snippet on your site. -- [source](http://thenextweb.com/google/2012/10/01/google-tag-manager-lets-simplify-manage-sites-tracking-marketing-tags/)

> A Tag Management System (TMS) is solution that controls the deployment of externally hosted Javascript "page tags", very similar to what a Content Management System does for content. Probably the most known tag-based application known is Google Analytics, but other apps include simple social media interactions such as the Facebook Like or Tweet This buttons to more complex systems such as the Intense Debate or Disqus comments systems. -- [source](http://online-behavior.com/analytics/tag-management-systems-website-innovation)

So in your question, you can implement google analytics via custom event tracking code *or* you can install google tag manager and then code all your custom google analytics event hooks in it.

Answer (score 3):

The google analytics is for user tracking and website traffic analysis and statistics.

The Tag manager is to manage plugin to website like google analytics basically they are different.

You could add google analytics to your tag manager account and the only plugin you will add to your website it the tag manager

i have tried this already. 
hoping this was helpful.

thanks (=

Answer (score 1):

Let me share my experience of implementing custom event tracking with Google Tag Manager.

Goggles Tag Manager (GTM) is a layer between your website and Google Analytics (GA).

We can use GA code for event tracking but in this case we have to write JavaScript in the website code. We have to look for event and need to add GA code inside that event handler. Since we have updated code, now we have to wait for the code release cycle to make it available to live site.

Using GTM it is possible to handle custom event tracking without adding code to the website and we can test our implementation with GTM inbuilt debugger before deploying to production website, at anytime.

And there is one more design pattern where we can implement generic custom event tracking for the whole website without adding JavaScript, but adding data-attributes to links, buttons or div- what ever event we want to track just add your data-attributes to the link and those attributes will go to GTM trigger and if it matches the rule, that event will be tracked. This design pattern is good for any kind of generic custom event tracking. I have implemented custom click tracking number of times using this pattern, and I am happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Tag Manager makes tagging easy as it has quite a few builtin dom variables and event handlers for Click, Pageview, Custom Events etc.

It also allows you to manage various external vendors and sends them the data they need. (I.e., Facebook pixel)

It really is a great eco-system for non-developers to get involved in tagging and event tracking.