# Google Tag Manager iOS Integration – sending values to Google Analytics?

Tags: ios, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

So I’m following Google’s atrocious documentation for Google Tag Manager, investigating for my employer whether it’s “worth” switching from Google Analytics to using GTM. There’s a huge lack of clarity in the documentation of what the difference between the two is, but I’ve gleaned that GTM in fact seems to just give the marketing team a little more flexibility in the way they collate data on their end.

I’m struggling to understand exactly what benefits GTM has over a simple integration of GA (like we already have).

Secondly, and more technically, following through the examples with a completely fresh Google account, but nothing shows up in the real time view at all, no active users, nothing coming through. I’ve carbon-copied their example code, like so:

```
[self.tagManager.dataLayer push:@ {
    @"event"                  : @"openScreen",
    @"screenName"             : screen
}];
```

Has anyone done this? Do you need to do anything specific with it? Here’s what it looks like in GTM, I have no idea if it’s right:

[image]

Comment: First part of your question may be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640645/what-is-the-difference-between-google-tag-manager-and-google-analytics

Comment: That’s indeed a good start – thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to send a variable key called `event`, and map that on the GTM end to a data layer variable. It didn’t seem to know it was an Event until I did that. Completely undocumented on Google’s end, so no idea if that’s what you’re supposed to do.

Comment: Can you give us an example how you did it?